# Отсортировать массив по значению в объектах

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как мне отсортировать массив по возрастанию значения первого элемента массива свойства number?
То есть для данного примера на выходе я хочу получить тот же массив, только чтобы второй и третий элемент поменялись местами ( т.к. 1, 5, 10)?

```
let info = [  
    {  
        number: [1, 20],  
        str: ’i’  
    },  
    {  
        number: [10, 40],  
        str: ’football’  
    },  
    {  
        number: [5, 40],  
        str: ’love’  
    }  
];
```

Comment: Решение, которое привёл Ростислав, конечно, правильное, но вы должны понимать как это работает и попробовать написать этот алгоритм без встроенных методов. [Тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) описано, как работает сортировка вставками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let info = [{
    number: [1, 20],
    str: 'i'
  },
  {
    number: [10, 40],
    str: 'football'
  },
  {
    number: [5, 40],
    str: 'love'
  }
]

let infoSorted = info.sort((e1, e2) => e1.number[0] - e2.number[0])

console.log(infoSorted)
```